# Charles proxy: dynamic response modification at runtime

Tags: https, proxy, charles-proxy

Does Charles Proxy have an option to pass decoded SSL responses to a local or remote script, taking a modified response from it and passing it to the client/requester?

So far, modification of a response seems possible via static regex match/replace feature. I need this to be dynamic, using node or php or whatever.

Any ideas without rewriting a proxy myself?

Comment: Good question! I made some investigation but cannot find such option/config in Charles. It seems Charles does not expose interface on `Breakpoints`.

Comment: The only workaround I found so far myself is using "Remote Mapping" targeting to my own proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you use the [Scripting](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/script) Tool from Proxyman. It allows you to write Javascript code and modify the HTTP/HTTPS Requests or Responses at runtime.

Scripting also ships with plenty of [addons](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/addons) and [Snippet Code](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code) that you can copy&paste.

Disclaimer: I'm a creator of Proxyman. Hope this answer helps you